# OpenLayers 3 opacity overlapping

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've got some issues with OpenLayers 3 when displaying a Vector layer with opacity. The more I pan or zoom in the map, and the less transparency there is on the features. I think this comes from the Vector Source that loads several times the same features, which makes some kind of overlap on the same data. Here is my code for WFS layer, where `myStyle` is a ol.style.Style with opacity=0.3 :

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function(extent) {
        var url = gsWFS + '?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=' + lyrName + '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            jsonp: false,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                vectorSource.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
            }
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ maxZoom: 20 }))
});

var vecLyr = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: myStyle,
    visible: true
});
```

Here are some iamges of the map, on rendering (opacity=0.3) and after a few moves in the map (opacity should still be the same, it is in the object, but it's not on the map).

[image: Map on first use]
[image: Same map after moving]

Do you have any ideas of how to deal with this opacity problem ?

Comment: You propably add the same layer again and again. How do you add your vector layer on the map??? Unless you provide your full code we can only guess!

Comment: The code for creating the layer is in my first message, and then I just do :

`map.getLayers().insertAt(1, vecLyr);`

I thought this error could come from the loading strategy ?

Comment: The code above propably fires multiple times and not just once. As told provide full code or better make a fiddle to demonstrate your case. Help to get helped.

Comment: if map.getLayers() gives you more results than your expecting (if you have one layer it should have one result), then  it is likely that you are adding the layer more than once

Comment: Finally found my solution !! As I expected it, it's just a strategy matters. BBOX strategy should be sued instead of tiles, which makes :  
`strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox`  instead of :  

`strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ maxZoom: 20 }))`  
Tile strategy would load many times the same features....

Answer (score 1):

Final solution is using BBOX strategy instead of Tile

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        loader: function(extent) {
            var url = gsWFS + '?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=inforisq:' + lyrName + '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                jsonp: false,
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (response) {
                    vectorSource.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
                }
            });
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });
```